# Linking to iOS Safari's Share Menu

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

I'm helping to build a webpage that is mobile friendly. We are currently in beta and using the "Add to Homescreen" function of Safari on iOS to make the webpage appear as an app. Is there a way through javascript or html to code a link to Safari's share menu? We want to be able to access this share menu from the bookmark shortcut rather than having to be in the actual Safari browser on the phone.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but as of iOS Safari 12.2 and macOS Safari 12.1, Safari supports [Navigator.share()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share) to display the system share menu.

Answer (score -1):

The Share menu in Safari is a component of the browser, not the web page. It cannot be linked to.

If you want your users to activate the "Add to Homescreen" function of Safari, you will need to instruct them to press the Share button themselves.

Comment: We do instruct them to do this. I think I may have worded what we are trying to do poorly. When we are already in the "Add to Homescreen" feature where the web page appears to be an app, we want the user to somehow still have access to Safari's share button even though the webpage no longer appears to be on Safari due to the Add to Homescreen feature. Is it possible to access this menu from the shortcut version (as it is still a Safari webpage) or can that only be done when actually in Safari's browser?